# ListGridRecord in smartGWT not displaying items after '<'

Tags: smartgwt

I have a ListGrid with ListGridRecords where I am trying to display the straight xml output from a call I'm doing on the backend.  Here's an example:

```
lgr.setAttribute("XML", "<xml><response>Bob</response></xml>");
```

However, when it goes to display the contents of lgr in the ListGrid, it doesn't display it.  (i.e.  it is blank).  If I make the field editable, I can double click on the cell and it will then display it.  Also, if I get rid of the '<' symbols it displays as well.  However, that kind of defeats the purpose since I want to display the exact xml used.

Do I need to escape the '<' somehow in the ListGridRecord?  What is the best way to do this in GWT?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found a thread that seems to solve my problem at least halfway.  I would still like to enable the user to copy it without the encoded values, but at least now they can see it.  I believe I'll enable some sort of click handler on the fields to to enable the correct copying.

http://www.gwt-ext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2693